# Finding associations between different groups of characteristics

Tags: multilabel

I have a large set of data, and two distinct ways of labelling that data, that aren't inherently linked but I suspect they may be. Each method takes a piece of data and assigns it one or more labels, but there are no labels that overlap between the method. For example:

```
Item    Labels (A)          Labels (B)
Cow     (4 legs), (milk)    (white)
Chair   (4 legs)            (brown), (sit)
Coin    (value), (small)    (circle), (metal)
Fridge  (milk), (big)       (metal), (white)
```

Obviously this is a silly example but I just want to illustrate what I have.

What I want to do is some test to see if they are dependent, in that for each label from Labels (A) I want to calculate a group of labels from Labels (B) that it is associated with. For example the label `(milk)` from A is associated with `(white)` from B, as they "commonly" coincide on the same item.

What's a good way to do this?